# Perl hash is full then empty

Tags: perl, hash

Some problems with hashing as I move to Perl 5 on a new server:

I have a hash called %hash that appears full of word=>family pairs (went=>go) when I test it thus:

```
   while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%hash)) { print " $key => $value\n";  }
```

However, when I try to get the value for a given key ~

```
    if ( $hash{$word} ) {...
```

~ the output is nil even when I know it cannot be! There must be something obviously wrong with this but I am looking my eyes out

Comment: In the debugger if you enter `x %hash` what do you see?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that will run and fail unexpectedly?  Failing code is more useful than code snippets.

Comment: Where does `$word` come from?

Comment: You're probably doing `my $word = <>;` and so you have a newline at the end of the word. So you need `chomp(my $word = <>);`

Comment: Thanks all - this is getting me somewhere

Comment: So here is the solution, which may help a few others who are moving to Apache: '$word' comes from a natural text, which is matched against a simple list of word-and-family pairs in 25 sets of family lists (dogs\ndog\ndoggy\ndog) that can be split into a %hash such that $hash{'doggy'} yields dog and any text can thus be reduced to its family components (as at www.lextutor.ca/familizer/).
 The problem was at splitting on \n. Moving Windows -> Apache server, I hadn't noticed that CRLF line endings had changed to Unix-style LF only. See http://serverfault.com/questions/311832/ 
  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't give a detailed description of code, I can just infer your problem:

1.Your hash actually didn't have a key $word.Please check it.

2.The value for key $work is just an empty string "" or an number 0 or "\0",all these conditions will lead your if($hash{$word}) return false even though your hash for this key has values.So ,check it again.

Comment: Yeah the mass move to a new server has created empty strings... Trying your suggestions has moved the file forward

Answer (score 0):

To see if `$word` is malformed, try doing:

use Data::Dumper ;

```
sub test
{
  my ($hashref, $key) = @_ ;

  print "Before: " . Dumper( $hashref ) ;
  if ( $key ~~ $hashref ) { print "found $key : $hashref->{$key}\n" ; }
  else
  {
     $hashref->{$key} = "NOT FOUND" ;
    print "After: " . Dumper( $hashref ) ;
  }
}
```

Then look to see what's different in the two hashes.

Comment: Don't use smartmatch, use `if (exists $hashref->{$key})`.

Answer (score -2):

> However, when I try to get the value for a given key (`if ( $hash{$word} ) {...`)  the output is nil

`if ( $hash{$word} )` is not how you print the value of a hash element. `print $hash{$word};` is.

Comment: That was just an nitial test to see if the word "had" a family (like, doggy->dog is a standard family but not Dougey=> Doug)

Comment: The answer is still to use `print $hash{$word}` instead of whatever unspecified code you did use.